# JAVA: Calling Unknown Object Class Method and Passing it's Parameters

Tags: java, object, methods, parameters, instance

The objective is simple, I want to create a method which load a class dynamically, access its method and passing their parameters value and getting the return value at run-time.

Class which will be called

```
class MyClass {

    public String sayHello() {

        return "Hello";
    }

    public String sayGoodbye() {

        return "Goodbye";
    }

    public String saySomething(String word){
        return word;
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
public class Main {


    public void loadClass() {
        try {

            Class myclass = Class.forName(getClassName());

            //Use reflection to list methods and invoke them
            Method[] methods = myclass.getMethods();
            Object object = myclass.newInstance();

            for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
                if (methods[i].getName().startsWith("saySome")) {
                    String word = "hello world";

                    //**TODO CALL OBJECT METHOD AND PASS ITS PARAMETER**
                } else if (methods[i].getName().startsWith("say")) {

                    //call method
                    System.out.println(methods[i].invoke(object));
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getClassName() {

        //Do appropriate stuff here to find out the classname

        return "com.main.MyClass";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        new Main().loadClass();
    }
}
```

My question is how to invoke method with parameters and passing its value? also getting the return value and its type.

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-dynamic-class-loading-java-reflection-api/

Comment: `System.out.println(methods[i].invoke(object, word));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're just missing the fact that you can pass in arguments to `invoke`, as an `Object[]`:

```
Object result = methods[i].invoke(object, new Object[] { word });
```

Or using varargs, if you prefer:

```
Object result = methods[i].invoke(object, word);
```

(The above two calls are equivalent.)

See the documentation for [`Method.invoke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) for more details.

Comment: that's it, yes my mistake.. the second param of `methods[i].invoke` is for the arguments..thanks Jon

Answer (score 1):

simply create the object of `MyClass` invoke the function like this

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
String word = "hello world";
String returnValue = mc.saySomething(word);
System.out.println(returnValue);//return hello world here
```

or do this

```
Class myclass = Class.forName(getClassName());
Method mth = myclass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, params);
Object obj = myclass.newInstance();
String result = (String)mth.invoke(obj, args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  ::

```
Class c = Class.forName(className); 
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, params);
Object i = c.newInstance();
String result = (String)m.invoke(i, args);
```